# Как добавить "basic authentication" к Frontier::Daemon XML-RPC сервису?

Tags: xml, http, perl, сервисы

Сервис XML-RPC

**Клиент**:

```
my $server_url = 'http://127.0.0.1:6000/RPC2';

my $server     = Frontier::Client->new(
    url      => $server_url,
    username => 'token',
    password => $token
) or  die "Не могу выполнить : $!";

my $result = $server->call('sample.calc', $arg)  or  die "Не могу выполнить : $!";
```

**Сервер**:

```
...
my $methods = { 'sample.calc' => \&calc };
my $d = Frontier::Daemon->new(
    LocalPort => 6000, 
    methods   => $methods
) or die "Couldn't start HTTP server: $!";

sub calc {....}
```

Сервис XML-RPC работает,  без проблем, но необходима basic authentication клиента. Пробовал, вытаскивать заголовки, но проблему это не решило:

```
while (my $c = $d->accept) {
   if (my $r = $c->request->header('Authorization')) { ... }
```

Как добавить базовую проверку подлинности сюда?